# image object is lost

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

My Extention passes a Model to fluid via

```
$this->view->assign('theSingleData',    $object);
$this->view->assign('theMultipleData',  $multipleObjects);
```

the object/thedata contains  an image:

f:debug of theSingleData gives me this:

```
image => TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReferenceprototypepersistent entity (uid=17069, pid=341)
```

perfect. I can render the image with 
`<f:image....>`

but 'theMultipleData' I process this way since its an array (just tested: it IS an array of 10 objects):

```
<f:for each="{theMultipleData}" as="item">
 <f:debug inline="true">{item}</f:debug>
</f:for>
```

this is fine for all fields but the image:

'Extbase Variable Dump
image => '1' (1 chars)'

Where is my object gone????

Comment: The problem here is different than described in the english mailinglist / forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign multiple data you should use the corresponding method:

```
$this->view->assignMultiple($multipleObjects);
```

while `$multipleObjects` is an array with pairs of key and value:

```
$multipleObjects = [
    'key1' => $value1,
    'key2' => $value2,
    'key3' => $value3,
    ...
];
```

In the template you have the values then available by the keys: `{key1}`, `{key2}`, `{key3}`, ...

So in general you can treat each pair like a common assignement you did with

```
$this->view->assign('key1', $value1);
$this->view->assign('key2', $value2);
$this->view->assign('key3', $value3);
...
```

I'd advise to use the method  `$this->view->assignMultiple()` I mentioned above and then it will work if everything else is fine.

Details about the method `$this->view->assignMultiple()` you find [here](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/interface_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_mvc_1_1_view_1_1_view_interface.html#a293620b2352f23c6f569bdd92a4bd592).

Comment: This is not a solutin: assign and assignMultiple are equivalent, the secound does use an array as parameter:

'exampl 1:
$this->view->assign('key1', $value1);
$this->view->assign('key2', $value2);'

'example 2: 
$myAssign = ['key1' => $value1, 'key1' => $value1];
$this->assignMultiple($myAssign);'

example1 and example2 are equivalent.

$this->view->assign('key3', $value3);

Again: my '$key1' is only ONE object, $key2 is an array of these Objects, and the image is lost.. Thanks for your try.

Comment: Did you try `<f:debug inline="true">{theMultipleData.item}</f:debug>`, @Eumolpius ?

Comment: ... or on upper level outside the loop just `<f:debug>{theMultipleData}</f:debug>`?